# With 'picture' in Facebook's Feed Dialog deprecated how can I post an image link?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been using Facebook's Feed Dialog to let users on a site share content on their Facebook feed. On their feed there would be a picture that serves as a link to the page on my site, with some text below it (name, caption and description fields). All of these -  picture, name, caption and description are now deprecated and stop working on July 17th. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality using a different method?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I now understand that I may not have been specific enough in my post. I would like users to be able to share the link to a page, but not from the page itself. I did that before by having them click a link on a different page that fired up javascript code that used the feed dialog. Of course, the first time they did that they needed to approve my Facebook app. Is there still a way to do that now without the feed dialog?

Comment: What does where you trigger the sharing _from_ have to do with this? _“Of course, the first time they did that they needed to approve my Facebook app”_ - no idea what you are talking about; using the _dialogs_ never required any approval from anyone, the user is in full control.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog one of the required parameters is an app id

Comment: So the basic question is how you can manipulate title/description/thumbnail, when sharing content that is not yours? Well you can’t any more, that is the whole _point_ of this deprecation.

Answer (score 33):

You need to use the Open Graph actions method described at the bottom of this page [here in the FB dev docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#advancedtopics).

> Trigger a Share Dialog using the [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui) function with the
>   share_open_graph method parameter to share an Open Graph story.

Try this within your code to specify a custom image, title, description or link on your FB shares:

```
    // this loads the Facebook API
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        var appId = '1937011929814387';
        FB.init({
            appId: appId,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v2.9'
        });
    };

    // FB Share with custom OG data.
    (function($) {

        $('.fb_share_btn').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                // Dynamically gather and set the FB share data. 
                var FBDesc      = 'Your custom description';
                var FBTitle     = 'Your custom title';
                var FBLink      = 'http://example.com/your-page-link';
                var FBPic       = 'http://example.com/img/your-custom-image.jpg';

                // Open FB share popup
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'share_open_graph',
                    action_type: 'og.shares',
                    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
                        object: {
                            'og:url': FBLink,
                            'og:title': FBTitle,
                            'og:description': FBDesc,
                            'og:image': FBPic
                        }
                    })
                },
                function (response) {
                // Action after response
                })
        })

    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: You're a genius, couldn't find this anywhere and almost gave up on adding custom content to the share popup!

Comment: When you call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`, you no longer need `event.stopPropagation()`, because `stopImmediatePropagation` does that too, the only difference is that it stops propagation with the target included.

Comment: What if we use mobile_iframe: true ? It's not working when you set mobile-iframe: true.

Comment: 2018 answer: these methods have been deprecated in the current api (which is why they're not listed anywhere in their docs). The effect is that the image size appears to be inconsistent and at some point it will likely fail to work at all. Confirmed by FB themselves: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1783400898620381/

Answer (score 0):

Currently (12/2019) you have to use the OG tags set in the URL for the share, so dynamically update the OG tags in your page based on the url...I recommend each object on your page have a url based on params passed in.  See this FB bug for an explanation https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1783400898620381/