# Laravel og:image not working

Tags: laravel-5.5, meta-tags

i have

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ url('/images/logo.jpg') }}"/>
```

but no one social network not show my image. What the problem?

Answer (score 1):

To share a dynamic image, you can't do it like that. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog will help you to do this using JavaScript.

Further development, like [set image from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44756939/with-picture-in-facebooks-feed-dialog-deprecated-how-can-i-post-an-image-link/45090955) you can do it like this. It worked for me.